# Thread.sleep method halts the thread permenantly

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
class SelfishRunner extends Thread{
     private int tick = 1;
     private int num ;
     public     SelfishRunner(int x){
             this.num = x;
     }
     @Override
     public void run(){
          try{
               while(tick < 400000){
                  Thread.sleep(250);
                  if((tick%50000) == 0){
                       System.out.println(" Thread# "+num+","+Thread.currentThread().getName()+", tick "+tick);
                       }
                  tick++;
              }
            }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println(e);
             }
         }
    }


    public class RaceDemo{
          private final static int NUMRUNNERS = 2;  
          public static void main(String[] args){
               SelfishRunner[] runners = new SelfishRunner[NUMRUNNERS];
               for(int x=0,y=1; x < NUMRUNNERS; x++){
                       runners[x] = new SelfishRunner(x);
                       runners[x].setPriority(y++);
               }
               runners[0].setName("JEEPERS");
               runners[1].setName("KREEPERS");
               for(int x=0; x < NUMRUNNERS; x++){
                   runners[x].start();
               }
          }
   }
```

The above code is trying to create a race condition, but in `SelfRunner.run` the call to `Thread.sleep(250)` halts program execution without printing output to the command line.

When I comment out that line, it works fine.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(250)` will make the thread sleep for 250 ms (1/4 second). It will print something for every 50,000 iterations. That means you'll have to wait 50,000 / 4 = 12,500 seconds (3 hours, 28 minutes, 20 seconds) before it prints something. Did you have that much patience?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do realize that you are only printing something every 50000/4 seconds, right? You might want to wait a little bit longer. :)

Comment: The time is up now - has it printed anything?